# Trouble Packaging Firefox Extension

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I have followed a couple different links that show how to package Firefox extensions. In cfx, my extension runs exactly how I want it. I made my install.rdf and zipped my files, changing the file type to xpi. When I install it in live Firefox, it shows up in my installed extensions, but nothing happens. I have also tried just using the base install.rdf that they post as a sample, but no luck. What am I missing here?

[Here's one guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Building_an_Extension#Create_the_Install_Manifest) I've been working off of.

Comment: This guide isn't for SDK addons, btw. `cfx` makes an xpi file for you.

Comment: There are cases where a user would need to edit the install.rdf and about packagin it: I don't know much but you have to do `make cfx` somehow. Search for that. :)

Comment: @Noitidart I agree, but you still do `cfx xpi`, then unpack and repack. It seems like @JasePellerin didn't know about `cfx xpi`.

Comment: Yep, I didn't even know that was a thing. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using [`cfx xpi`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx#cfx_xpi) to package your addons, not the docs you pointed to. As @Noitidart pointed out, there are reasons to unpackage that `xpi` file and repackage it, and that is mentioned in the above link.

There are three ways to make extensions for Firefox. When you're using the add-on SDK (one of the ways), make sure all the docs you're reading are under the [developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/) path.

Note that Firefox is making the [move from `cfx` to `jpm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/cfx_to_jpm), so unless you need your extensions to be available on [AMO](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/) very soon, you should use [`jpm`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/jpm).